# R pipe operator %T>%

Tags: r

who will advise me on the %T>%,

the code is

```
c(1031, 8, 0, 968, 66, 12) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 3) %>% 
  'colnames<-'(c("Improved", "Hospitalized", "Death")) %>% 
  'rownames<-'(c("Treated", "Placebo")) %>% 
  as.table %T>% fisher.test %>% chisq.test
```

however, it always bypass the fisher.test just conduct the chisq.test. my plan is the data will be output into fisher and chisq test respectively.

your advice is highly appreciated!

Charles

Comment: In order to Tee-pipe the data the functions need to invisibly return the data so you can pipe it further. Functions inside `tidyverse` do this by design, but others don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Tee pipe for this.

```r
library(magrittr)

c(1031, 8, 0, 968, 66, 12) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 3) %>% 
  'colnames<-'(c("Improved", "Hospitalized", "Death")) %>% 
  'rownames<-'(c("Treated", "Placebo")) %>% 
  as.table %>% 
  {fisher.test(.) %>% print() 
   chisq.test(.) %>% print()}
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#> 
#> data:  .
#> p-value < 2.2e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
#> 
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  .
#> X-squared = 2012.4, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is a real smart way. however, as a beginner, I just want to practise the %T>% use

Answer (score 1):

The problem is although the data is returned after your test, your test result is not printed. This can be overcomed by defining a `Print` functional that forces the print of each step. Then you can `%T>%` as many times as you want. One benefit of this is that you can also "switch off" those steps that you do not want to be printed to the console by just stripping off the `Print` wrapper.

```
library(magrittr)

Print <- function(f) function(x) print(f(x))

c(1031, 8, 0, 968, 66, 12) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 3) %>% 
  'colnames<-'(c("Improved", "Hospitalized", "Death")) %>% 
  'rownames<-'(c("Treated", "Placebo")) %>% 
  as.table %T>% Print(fisher.test)() %T>% Print(chisq.test)() %T>% Print(t.test)()
```

Note that the `()` after `Print(...)` is compulsory.

Output

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  x
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x
X-squared = 2012.4, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16


    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 1.6823, df = 5, p-value = 0.1533
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -183.4795  878.4795
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    347.5 

        Improved Hospitalized Death
Treated     1031            0    66
Placebo        8          968    12
```